# Error ,CronJob Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, cron

I set the CronJob with cmd :`20 * * * * wget –spider -O – http://172.104.177.93/demo > /dev/null 2>&1`is okay, but when running Cronjob with cmd is:`20 9 * * * wget –spider -O – http://172.104.177.93/demo > /dev/null 2>&1`,then CronJob does not run. It's hard to understand

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, we need to distinguish the problem is the cron problem or the command problem, so I recommend you modify the command to `20 * * * * wget –spider -O – http://172.104.177.93/demo >> /tmp/cron 2>&1` and wait the cronjob is executed by cron, then check the `/tmp/cron`:

- If the file does not exist, it should be a cron problem, go to check the cron daemon setting. Ubuntu have a help [page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto) for it.
- If the file exists, it should be the command problem, go to check the error message in the `/tmp/cron` and fix the problem.